# How to use a variable to index ${array[*]} in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, indexing

First of all sorry because my english may be not good.
I want to use a variable to index an element in an array or use the same variable to index all the elements. For example:

```
...
var1="1"
var2="*"
array=(one two three for five)

for elem in ${array[$var1]}
do
  echo $elem
done
```

When I use *var1* to index in ***${array[$var1]}*** it works correctly, but if I use *var2* doesn't work correctly, I get this error:

```
./ed.sh line XXX *: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*")
```

I'm pretty sure that the error is related with the * wildcard expansion, but I didn't find an answer that help me to solve this problem. So, how can I do it?

Comment: What exactly is the result you're looking for? Your array does not have an index that is `*`, because non-associative arrays only have integers as keys.

Comment: @ghoti: `${array[*]}` is valid for indexed arrays, it displays all the elements of the array.  `${!array[*]}` displays all the indexes that have values, which can be useful because these arrays are sparse.  The problem here is the expansion order, which even `eval` does not appear to fix.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for including complete, dependency-free code to reproduce the problem plus a complete error message!  +1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*` and `@` are not considered regular elements in the array. They are not listed when iterating keys, and are not considered when expanding indirectly through index variables.

The bash [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?id=eb78197af36bb0fb95493ebf8fce104be6832ec9#n6449) has a function `chk_atstar` that checks whether `[@]` or `[*]` is being used, and you can see that it's done literally and not through any expansion:

```
else if (valid_array_reference (name, 0))
  {
    temp1 = mbschr (name, '[');
    if (temp1 && temp1[1] == '@' && temp1[2] == ']')
      {
```

If you really want to do this, you can go through variable indirection:

```
arr=(one two three)
index='*'
var="arr[$index]"
echo "${!var}"
```

though you may be better off not trying to treat these special array access modes as array elements.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend this, but for completeness you can get this to work by cheating with the expansion order using `eval`:

```
eval items=\${array[$var2]}
for elem in $items
do
    echo $elem
done
```

There are issues with this.  `eval` is generally pronounced "evil" because there can be security implications in running code from a variable.  There is usually a better way to do the job than using `eval`.  In this case you should give some thought to the design.

There is also an issue if an element contains embedded whitespace.  Add:

```
array+=('at the end')
```

After the array declaration and you'll see what I mean.

EDIT:  After some deliberation, here is a way to do it *without* `eval`, and it supports embedded spaces or tabs (but not embedded newlines).  Pretty it is not:

```
display_it() {
    if [[ $1 = '*' ]]; then
        oldIFS="$IFS"
        IFS=$'\n'
        echo "${array[*]}"
        IFS="$oldIFS"
    else
        echo "${array[$1]}"
    fi
}

var1="1"
var2="*"
array=(one two three for five)
array+=('at the end')

while read -r elem
do
  echo $elem
done < <(display_it "$var2")
```

Displays:

```
one
two
three
for
five
at the end
```

At the end of the loop you will see *process substitution* where I call the function `display_it`.  Each item read is separated by a newline, hence the swapping of the Internal Field Separator (`IFS`) in the function.

Comment: Scalar arrays already evaluate variables as code, so `eval` (sadly) doesn't actually introduce a new security issue in this case